# Replace shortcut path during creation (Windows)

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, file-shortcut

I would like all new shortcut links created using the right-click option in windows explorer to replace the absolute path with a system variable. The motivation is to have synchronized shortcuts work across different systems.

For example, let's say I have a synced folder called synced.
On system A, this folder is at D:\synced
On system B, this folder is at E:\synced

Furthermore, I have defined system variables to map to the synced folder on each system.
On system A, %syn% resolves to D:\synced
On system B, %syn% resolves to E:\synced

Is there a way to create shortcuts quickly that replaces absolute paths with a specific system variable? For example, I would like to right-click a folder and create a shortcut with the system variable %syn% replacing the absolute path D:\synced at the top of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Its almost like I don't understand your question, because the answer is so plain obvious, so if this is not what you're seeking, please update your question and explain it further.

Basically, create a new shortcut, and put as target %syn% (just type it in) and it will always refer to the right path. The target will remain %syn% but once clicked it will follow your path unless the path doesn't exist, then it throws in an error, like with any other shortcut.

You can even copy/paste this shortcut to other pc's and it will remain in tact.